# How to use apolloClient's 'onSuccess' only once the useMutation has executed successfully

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, apollo-client

I need to be able to perform a function (closeModal), when the useMutation (insert/update query) executes with success, and before or on each reRender.

If I uncomment the code in the onClose function from the 'useMutation' function, then from the parent I can't open the modal
(open close and toggle are handled by the parent, ..see beneath)

Modal child:

```
 export default function DeviceModal(props) {
    const device = useQuery(getDevice_query, {variables: {id: dataRowId}});
    const [dbUpdate,{ data, loading, error }] = useMutation(insertDevice_query,
    {
        //onSuccess: onClose(),
    });

    const onClose = () => {
        props.closeModal();
    };

return ( ModalMarkup );
}
```

Parent:

```
const [isModalShown, toggleModal] = React.useState(false);
const closeModal = () => {
    toggleModal(false)
}
const openModal = () => {
    toggleModal(true)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the wrong option to the `useQuery` hook. There is no `onSuccess` parameter in appolo client v3. You need to replace it with `onCompleted`. Now whete you're using the `useMutation` or `useQuery` you should pass the `onCompleted` rather than `onSucess`. So your code will be look like this.

```
    export default function DeviceModal(props) {
    const device = useQuery(getDevice_query, {variables: {id: dataRowId}});
    const [dbUpdate,{ data, loading, error }] = useMutation(insertDevice_query,
    {
        onCompleted: ()=>{
         onClose();
    },
    });

    const onClose = () => {
        props.closeModal();
    };

      return ( ModalMarkup );
    }
```

[Check here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#params) `useQuery` params.

[Check here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#params-2) `useMutation` params.

Answer (score 0):

One options is to pass a function as a prop to `DeviceModal` and then call it in your success handler. For example:

```
<DeviceModal closeModal={closeModal} />
```

```
onSuccess: props.closeModal()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the return promise where the hook is called, i.e. use .then as below

```
const [dbUpdate,{ data, loading, error }] = useMutation(insertDevice_query);

const handleSubmit = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const deviceRec = recState;
    dbUpdate({ variables: {device: deviceRec}})
        .then( onClose() );
};
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 